# Flickr API JSON pull set

Tags: jquery, json, api, flickr

I'm building a fairly simple unlimited photopage which gets photos from a Flickr set. I have the following code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

var apiKey = 'XXX';
var userId = 'XXX';
var photoset_id = 'XXX';

$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, FlickrPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + data.photos.FlickrPhoto[i].farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + data.photos.FlickrPhoto[i].server + '/' + data.photos.FlickrPhoto[i].id + '_' + data.photos.FlickrPhoto[i].secret + ".jpg";            

        var a_href = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + FlickrPhoto.id + "/";
        $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL).appendTo("#photographs").wrap(("<div class='item'></div>"))
    });
});
});
```

I'm receiving the following error and i can't seem to figure out why. Probably major fail but not seeing it..

```
TypeError: data.photos is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

...asePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + data.photos.FlickrPhoto[i].farm + '.static.flickr....
```

Comment: Well for one, XXX isn't a valid photoset ID and neither is the user_id and api_key. I can understand not wanting to put your apikey in here, but there isn't really a way for us to test what is breaking without them.

Comment: Really? I have to give out my private keys in order to get help? Strange..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your JQuery `$.each`. You do not need to use `i` to index each photo. The function is executed for every element in the `photo` array. `flickrPhoto` therefore represents each item from `data.photoset.photo`, so you don't need to prepend it with `data.photos`.

```
$.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, flickrPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + ".jpg";            

        var a_href = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + flickrPhoto.id + "/";
        $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL).appendTo("#photographs").wrap(("<div class='item'></div>"))
});
```

Comment: Seems logical indeed. I'll try this when i get home from work. Thanks for the feedback!